# How to run a jar located in local drive from a jenkins job?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, executable-jar, jenkins-job-dsl

I have created a job which creates a jar using maven & that jar gets stored in a local drive. I want to create a new job which runs that jar.

pom.xml for reference:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>Backend_Automation</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>11</source>
          <target>11</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <mainClass>com.vodafone.hackathon.runner.CoreRunner</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

    </plugins>
  </build>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>Backend_Automation</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

this project is checked in on github repository. first job builds the project from the github repository and builds the project and creates the jar at a local place mentioned in the job. I tried adding shell commands but it did not worked.

Comment: Could you elaborate how the shell command "did not worked"? Did it give you an error message? What was the message?

Answer (score 0):

If the jar is installed on the same machine where the jenkins job will run then you can call the shell with a hard-coded path.

e.g.

```
pipeline {
  agent { label '...' }    <-- Need to specify agent that has the jar
  stages {
    stage('Run Jar') {
       sh "java /var/lib/mylib/mylib-1.0.0.jar ..."
    }
  }
}
```

But best practice is to have one job that runs "mvn clean deploy" to upload the jar file to a remote repository (nexus or artifactory), then another job that downloads the jar artifact to its workspace and executes the jar:

```
pipeline {
  agent { label 'os-linux' }   <-- any agent running linux
  stages {
    stage('Install Jar') {
      ... download jar from artifactory to e.g. ${WORKSPACE}/mylib.jar ..  
    }
    stage('Run Jar') {
      sh "java ${WORKSPACE}/mylib.jar ..."
    }
  }
}
```

This will allow the jenkins job to run on multiple agents (rather than the very specific single agent in the first example above).

The "download jar from artifactory" comment could be implemented using a curl command, or you could use the artifactory plugin to define a download spec, etc.